# Why PySide6 application crashes when hovering over custom button while executing several QRunnables in QThreadPool

Tags: concurrency, pyside6, pyqt6, paintevent, qrunnable

My first question on Stackoverflow: I'll try my best to explain the problem ;-)

I'm currently playing around with a Python application based on PySide6.
There are several time-consuming calculations running as `QRunnable` instances in `QThreadPool.globalInstance()`. So far everything is working well.

I also added a modified `QPushButton` to the UI. Now the problem is that the application crashes when I hover over the button while `QRunnables` are running in the background.

I created a minimal reproducible example. A very simple worker (`QRunnable`) that only waits 1 second and emits `Signal` *finished* when completed.

file **q_worker.py**

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable, Signal, Slot
from time import sleep

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
finished = Signal()

class WorkerSleep(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerSleep, self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
    
    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        sleep(1)
        self.signals.finished.emit()
```

In `main.py` you find the class `CustomButton` where just the method `paintEvent` is overwritten. Further a window with one `CustomButton` and one `QLabel` is created.

file **main.py**

```py
import sys
import os

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QThreadPool, QTimer, Slot
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, QPaintEvent, QLinearGradient

from q_worker import WorkerSleep

class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(650, 99)

    def paintEvent(self, event: QPaintEvent):
        fill_color = QLinearGradient.Preset.TemptingAzure

        with QPainter(self) as p:
            p.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
            rect = event.rect()
            p.fillRect(rect, fill_color)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle('minimal reproducible example')

        # time in seconds, before workers are created
        self._count = 5

        # number of workers
        self._num_workers_to_create = 100
        self._num_workers_completed = 0

        self._setup_ui()
        self.show()

        # start countdown to create workers
        self._timer = QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self._countdown)
        self._timer.start(1000)
    
    def _setup_ui(self):
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
    
        # add ui elements
        self.label_counter = QLabel(f"<span style= font-size:25pt>{self._count}</span>")
        central_widget_layout.addWidget(self.label_counter, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter)
        central_widget_layout.addWidget(CustomButton(parent=self))
    
    @Slot()
    def _countdown(self):
        self._count -= 1
        self.label_counter.setText(f"<span style= font-size:25pt>{self._count}</span>")
    
        if self._count == 0:
            self._timer.stop()
            self._create_workers()
    
    def _create_workers(self):
        for i in range(self._num_workers_to_create):
            worker = WorkerSleep()
            worker.signals.finished.connect(self._update_completed_workers)
            QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)
    
    @Slot()
    def _update_completed_workers(self):
        num_threads = str(QThreadPool.globalInstance().activeThreadCount())
        self._num_workers_completed += 1
        self.label_counter.setText(f"<span style= font-size:25pt>"
                                   f"{self._num_workers_completed} Workers completed "
                                   f"({num_threads} Threads running)</span>")

def main():
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
sys.exit(main())
```

When running the example, the window opens, a timer counts down 5 seconds, and then `WorkerSleep` is started 100 times in `QThreadPool.globalInstance()`. As long as I don't hover over the button, everything works fine. However, when I hover over the button while the workers are being processed, the application crashes.

At first I thought it was because too many `QRunnables` were added to `QThreadPool.globalInstance()`. However, according to the documentation, they will be queued when `QThreadPool.maxThreadCount()` is reached. And this seems to work perfectly as `QThreadPool.globalInstance().activeThreadCount()` is always 8 which is the default value.

After making further attempts, the problem appears to be in the `CustomButton`. Because if a standard `QPushButton` is used, everything works perfectly.

So if I remove the custom `paintEvent` everything works as expected. So it seems there is something wrong with this method. But no matter what changes I try to this method, it keeps crashing.

Last but not least, there is another super strange phenomenon that I have no explanation for: when I initialize the button with a smaller size

```py
class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(650, 50)
```

the application works fine whith my `CustomButton` and my custom `paintEvent`.

I'm running Windows 10, **Python 3.9.9** and **PySide6 v.6.4.1**

---

i tried the following:

- adding `setAutoDelete(False)` to `WorkerSleep.__init__` did not solve the problem
- running from the (Windows) console in venv led to the same result
- i also tried on a complete different windows machine with a new venv - running from the console lead to the same result
- i upgraded PySide6 version to current v.6.6.0 and look here - then it worked

I'm not able to solve the problem with Python 3.9.9 and PySide 6.4.1?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this at all on arch-linux using Qt-6.6.0 with PySide-6.6.0. Please edit your question and provide details of the platform you are testing on and the *specific* versions of Qt6 and PySide6 you are using. If you're using an IDE, test the script in a normal console / command-window instead. You should also try reproducing the problem using a PyQt6 version of the script.

Comment: @ekhumoro I cannot reproduce it too, either with the latest Qt5 and 6 on a virtual machine, but I can on a physical one with an older Qt5 version. It may be related to the way the threadpool tries to destroy the QRunnable while the signal is being processed: adding a reference to the worker doesn't seem to solve it, but `setAutoDelete(False)` will. There was a change in the private `::clear()` in Qt5 (unlock of the mutex created in that context), but since it also exists in Qt6 I don't see how this would relate (and my knowledge about multithreading is insufficient for this).

Comment: @chris1656 Can you check if there is some change if you add `self.setAutoDelete(False)` to the `__init__` of your runnable subclass?

Comment: @chris1656 Also, can you please explain what you actually do within those runnables? It's possible that using QRunnable may not be the correct approach, and maybe you just need a system that manages a few persistent QThreads and eventually assigns them their tasks using a Queue.

Comment: @chris1656 Ok, but this doesn't really explain the issue. Also note that the suggestion to run the script in a terminal/prompt doesn't necessarily give a different behavior, but it's intended to eventually get a different *output* (which some IDEs are not always capable of). Also, setting `autoDelete()` may not be sufficient, and you probably need to also add the `worker` instance to a persistent list. I understand that you may have solved the issue *now*, but it could still be a problem for people that cannot use your version (or even find unrelated bugs). Don't just settle, investigate.

Comment: Also, please don't add solutions to questions (you already took the [tour]: this isn't a forum), the answer section is exactly for that, while the question part shouldn't include them, otherwise the post may become confusing to people that may not have the knowledge about your *current* situation, including its location in a software version timeframe. Please take your time to read [ask], review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and always try to put yourself in other people's shoes (including different time periods when reading the same question, or even different contexts).

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for that information. I edited the question again. I also removed the solution answer because, as you describe, it didn't solve the actual problem.
Since I unfortunately couldn't solve the problem with PySide v.6.4.1 after many hours, I will continue with the current PySide v.6.6.0.